# ElastiCache Autodiscovery Magento

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache, autodiscovery

I'm with a problem to use ElastiCache nodes with Magento, because I'm not able to configure Autodiscovery merged with Magento.

Is possible to configure Magento just with the Host of the ElastiCache Cluster and use all the nodes simultaneously? (just as a cluster)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In the Elasticache console, click on Replication Groups, then pick your cluster from the list. Find the value for **Primary Endpoint** and use that as your cache host. This will point at the cluster and will properly handle node failover.

Comment: Replication Groups can be used just for Redis, I'm using Memcached cluster. When I set the cluster endpoint, it work as a load balancer. I wantedto set items to all the nodes at same time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the *ElastiCache Cluster Client* for your version of PHP? You'd have to build a module to edit local.xml or to otherwise change Magento's internal vars before the session or cache get used, but hopefully that's a start for you.